# Jaspersoft iReports designer 5.6.0; how to fix size of expression editor window

Tags: ireport

As I am working mainly with large expressions within iReport designer, I want to fix the window size of the expression editor of the iReport designer to a larger size compared with what it defaults to.

Each time I open the expression editor within the iReport designer, it defaults to a relatively small window and then I always have to re-arrange it. As a double click on the title bar doesn't do anything, this is using a considerable amount of time when I have to do this 100ths of time each day.

Is there a way to set the position, width and height of the iReport designer 5.6.0 (I don't use Jaspersoft Studio because of its even more time-consuming file save behavior) so that next time I open the expression editor it will use this position, width and height?

(I have already searched the internet, also here on SO - but nobody seems to have this problem)

Answer (score 0):

As I could nowhere find an answer to this I have quickly developed a workaround with AutoIt.

;Here the AutoIt code:

```
; *** Variables ***
$FrameInPercent = 10

do

   $hWindow = WinWaitActive("[CLASS:SunAwtDialog;TITLE:Expression editor]", "") ; *** Wait here until the Expression editor window is opened ***
   WinActivate($hWindow)

   ; *** Calculate distance from screen edge for Expression editor window ***
   $DeskSize = _GetWorkingArea()
   $WindowWidth = $DeskSize[2]-($DeskSize[2]*(0.01*2*$FrameInPercent))
   $WindowHeight = $DeskSize[3]-($DeskSize[3]*(0.01*2*$FrameInPercent))
   $windowStartLeft = ($DeskSize[2]*(0.01*$FrameInPercent))
   $windowStartTop = ($DeskSize[3]*(0.01*$FrameInPercent))

   WinMove($hWindow, "",$windowStartLeft, $windowStartTop, $WindowWidth, $WindowHeight)

   ;WinMove($hWindow, "",71, 116, 1815, 863)

   Do
      Sleep(1000) ; calmly idle around as long as the Expression editor window is    open
   until NOT(WinExists($hWindow))

until False ; *** Loop forever ***

;===============================================================================
;
; Credits for this function goes to: https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/53788-getting-windows-desktop-size/
; Function Name:    _GetWorkingArea()
; Description:    Returns the coordinates of desktop working area rectangle
; Parameter(s):  None
; Return Value(s):  On Success - Array containing coordinates:
;                       $a[0] = left
;                       $a[1] = top
;                       $a[2] = right
;                       $a[3] = bottom
;                  On Failure - 0
;
;===============================================================================
Func _GetWorkingArea()
#cs
BOOL WINAPI SystemParametersInfo(UINT uiAction, UINT uiParam, PVOID pvParam, UINT fWinIni);
uiAction SPI_GETWORKAREA = 48
#ce
    Local $dRECT = DllStructCreate("long; long; long; long")
    Local $spiRet = DllCall("User32.dll", "int", "SystemParametersInfo", _
                        "uint", 48, "uint", 0, "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($dRECT), "uint", 0)
    If @error Then Return 0
    If $spiRet[0] = 0 Then Return 0
    Local $aRet[4] = [DllStructGetData($dRECT, 1), DllStructGetData($dRECT, 2), DllStructGetData($dRECT, 3), DllStructGetData($dRECT, 4)]
    Return $aRet
EndFunc
```

---

In order to use this you have to install AutoIt: https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/

And then run this script (doubleclick it). The script will run forever but will not take much CPU power as it is event driven while waiting for the Expression editor to appear and while the expression editor is open, it only scans every 1 second if this window is still open.

Hope this helps someone.

As this is my first AutoIt script, optimizations are welcome :-)